# How to pass arguments while build with bazel

Tags: build, apache-flink, bazel

How to pass arguments while doing bazel build. Actually my program will accepts two arguments .one is directory and the other one is target.csv
I need to get the files under a directory and write it to csv.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collector;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple1;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool;


public class ReadFiles {

  /**
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // set up the execution environment
    try {
      final ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
      final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

      env.setParallelism(1); // without this multiple files creating
      env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(params);

      List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
      File dir = new File(params.getRequired("input"));
      for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isFile()) {
          paths.add(f.getName());
        }
      }
      DataSet<String> data = env.fromCollection(paths).rebalance();
      DataSet<Tuple1<String>> output = data.flatMap(new CSVSplitter());
      env.execute();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
// The operations are defined by specialized classes, here the Splitter class.


class CSVSplitter implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple1<String>> {

  public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Tuple1<String>> out) throws Exception {
    out.collect(new Tuple1<String>(value));
  }

}
```

And the syntax to build bazel which I am trying -

```
bazel build FlinkEx/com/practice:read_files
```

facing issues after executing this.

```
Worker process sent response with exit code: 1.
error: wrong number of type arguments; required 3
```

I need to pass arguments something like bazel build FlinkEx/com/practice:read_files c:/  c:/target.csv

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean `bazel run`?  You can pass in arguments by separating them from the Bazel invocation with `--`:

```
bazel run FlinkEx/com/practice:read_files -- c:/ c:/target.csv
```

Or you can run the binary directly and pass arguments "normally":

```
bazel build FlinkEx/com/practice:read_files
bazel-bin/FlinkEx/com/practice:read_files c:/ c:/target.csv
```

(This is assuming `bazel build` is putting `read_files` in `bazel-bin`. If it's under `bazel-genfiles`, just run it from there instead.)